# How to solve "ptrace operation not permitted"?

Tags: debugging, ubuntu-16.04, ptrace, klee

I am getting the following message:

```
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
The program is not being run.
KLEE: WARNING: KLEE: WATCHDOG: kill(9)ing child (I tried to be nice)
```

Whenever the watchdog is expired.

> KLEE: WARNING: KLEE: WATCHDOG: time expired, attempting halt via INT
>
> KLEE: ctrl-c detected, requesting interpreter to halt. KLEE: WARNING:
> KLEE: WATCHDOG: time expired, attempting halt via gdb

However, this program was running without any issues and was used to give the output based on whatever have been done till the watchdog expired.

I don't remember any major change that have been done in the past few days to invoke this issue.

Comment: Really depends on _why_, and there's more than one possible reason. To pick some low-hanging fruit... how was the process invoked? setuid and ptrace aren't compatible with each other.

Comment: Also, some processes will prevent anything else from attaching to them with ptrace by ptrace'ing _themselves_; it's not unheard of as a low-rent anti-reverse-engineering approach.

Comment: Anyhow -- to give a firm answer rather than speculation, we need a [mre] -- steps that, when followed, suffice to let us see the problem oursevles.

Comment: did you do it with `sudo`?